# How does the Strange PDA track "kills"?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

How does the Strange PDA work? I've heard conflicting reports that it tracks health dispensed and allies teleported, but it also seems that it counts sentry kills.

If so, how is the Strange prefix changed?

Also, do Allies Teleported count enemy spies taking your teleporter?

Comment: The item appears to track Sentry Kills & Health Dispensed, ranking up on Sentry Kills (see [this tf2b entry](http://tf2b.com/tf2/item/76561198016795930/1525344891)), but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The strange PDA tracks sentry kills, health dispensed (for dispensers), and allies teleported (for teleporters). However, only the **sentry kills** go toward the strange rank (the name changes). I believe that allies teleported pertains only toward allies and not enemy spies, as illustrated by other uses of the word "ally" in other in item descriptions. The name changes are like the normal ones. http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange#Ranks
http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/PDA